# How to animate UITabBarItem on position changing with vertical movement(up/down)?

Tags: swift, uikit

I am working on UITabBarItem positioning by changing the imageinset and title offset. After I add the transition, instead of transit vertically, it transits from left to right. May I ask is there any workaround for the UIView animation?

[image: Animation from left to right, instead of vertically]

```
class TabBarViewController : UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate{
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {

        let yChanges : CGFloat = 20

        for i in 0 ... tabBarController.tabBar.items!.count - 1{
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
                let isSelected =  (i == tabBarController.selectedIndex)
                let contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: isSelected ? -yChanges : 0, left: 0, bottom: isSelected ? yChanges : 0, right: 0)
                tabBarController.tabBar.items![i].imageInsets = contentInset
                tabBarController.tabBar.items![i].titlePositionAdjustment.vertical = (i == tabBarController.selectedIndex) ? -yChanges : 0
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4,
               delay: 0.0,
               usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0,
               initialSpringVelocity: 0.5,
               options: options,
               animations: {

    ///Your code
    
}, completion: nil)


  let options: UIView.AnimationOptions = isSelected ? [.curveEaseIn] : [.curveEaseOut]
  
  //note isSelected variable assign selected or not
```

and use

```
 .layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: Thank @Akila M for the answer. I had made some changes, I make change the inset/offset properties first and call .layoutIfNeeded() in the animation block. While it does not move from left to right, but the animation is like appear ease in/out rather than moveing up/down. May I ask is changing offset/inset is a bad way for animation?